# Magento 1 : Some active categories are not displaying in sitemap.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category, sitemaps

Two category pages are not displaying in sitemap.xml
these categories are active in backend, and also showing in frontend still my sitemap.xml is not displaying these two category pages.

Can any one help please.

Answer (score 0):

Check out if you are using Active From and/or Active To limitations. Additionally please check if Meta fields are not empty in General tab.